# I need to populate 2 select dropdowns onclicking 1 of 3 radio options

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I have searched high and low for any kind of similar answer all to no avail, I could really do with a little help or guidance on this, please.

Wordpress Real estate site,search form,  three contract types, for rent, for sale, short term rental, all three are radio inputs.
I have two select boxes populated with min and max prices for the search.
I need to be able to change the values of the min and max select box, depending on which radio button is selected.
My PHP is average (I could do this with reloading the page once a radio button is clicked, but would prefer to do it with JQuery if possible)
My JQuery/Java is poor, but trying to learn.

The $key for the price ranges is generated by the following code:

```
 $terms = get_terms( "contract_type");
        foreach ($terms as $term ) {
            $contract_types[$term->term_id] = $term->name;
        }

        foreach( $contract_types as $key => $value ) {

            if( array_key_exists("enable-{$key}-search", $property ) ):
        $checked = ($key == $_GET['searchby'] ) ? ' checked ':'';
            $title = dttheme_option("property","{$key}-title");
            echo "<input type='radio' id='{$key}' {$checked} value='{$key}' name='searchby' class='regular-radio' /><label for='{$key}'>{$title}</label>"; 

            endif;
                }
```

That populates the $key with with the contract references, 34, 35 and 55 respectively, seen here.. http://www.malisa.asia/property-search-2/

The select boxes are populated as:

```
            #Min price Rent Module
              if( $instance['price_module'] == 'true' ):
         echo '<div id="default" class="min-price-module small-module malisa-select">';
        echo '<label>'.__('Rent Range','dt_themes').'</label>';

        $min_prices = array_key_exists("min-price-for-{$key}", $property) ? $property["min-price-for-{$key}"] : array();
        $min_prices = array_filter($min_prices);
        $min_prices = array_unique($min_prices);

    echo select( "dt-min-price", "minprice", $min_prices, $currency, $selected), "\n\n";

     endif;

              #Max price default Module
              if( $instance['price_module'] == 'true' ):
        $max_prices = array_key_exists("max-price-for-{$key}", $property) ? $property["max-price-for-{$key}"] : array();
                $max_prices = array_filter($max_prices);
                $max_prices = array_unique($max_prices);
        echo select( "dt-max-price", "maxprice", $max_prices, $currency, $selected), "\n\n";

    echo '</div>';
      endif;

            #Min price Sale Module
              if( $instance['price_module'] == 'true' ):
         echo '<div id="default" class="min-price-module small-module malisa-select">';
         echo '<label>'.__('Sale Range','dt_themes').'</label>';
         $min_prices = array_key_exists("min-price-for-{$key}", $property) ? $property["min-price-for-{$key}"] : array();
         $min_prices = array_filter($min_prices);
         $min_prices = array_unique($min_prices);
          echo select( "dt-min-price", "minprice", $min_prices, $currency, $selected), "\n\n";

      endif;
```

This is within a form, so just hiding the select box isnt possible.
to see what we are trying to achieve, https://www.purplebricks.com/search#!
Could someone please point me in the right direction to achieve this, much appreciated.

Comment: you can dynamically replace the content of the dropdowns with jquery on the click event, so you need to create js functions to populate the dropdowns and not a bunch of pre-populated dropdowns. If you don't want to use ajax... you can also dynamically populate a JS array with php in `<script>` tags on site creation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply maraca, I suppose that was a perfect answer for a dumb question.. I will need to remember to word my questions a little more thorough next time.
Yes, exactly what I need to do, "dynamically replace the content of the dropdowns with jQuery on the click event".

PS, the bunch of three displayed select boxes are, no were, for reference to show the array $key value is populated with the three values from the contract types, thought it would make it easier for someone to give me a heads up.
Nevermind, the search will continue.

Answer (score 1):

You should do the following things:

1) Take two variables corresponding to minimum and maximum of the radio options for every radio options.

```
e.g.  var r_min,r_max,s_min,s_max,st_min,st_max;
```

2) On the combo-box change event, Save the minimum and maximum values in variables corresponding to the radio options.

```
jQuery('#dt-max-price').on('change',function(){
   if(jQuery('#34').is(':checked')){
       r_min=jQuery('#dt-min-price').val();
   }
   if(jQuery('#36').is(':checked')){      
       s_min=jQuery('#dt-min-price').val();
   }
   if(jQuery('#55').is(':checked')){     
       st_min=jQuery('#dt-min-price').val();
   }
});
jQuery('#dt-max-price').on('change',function(){
   if(jQuery('#34').is(':checked')){
      r_max=jQuery('#dt-max-price').val();
   }
   if(jQuery('#36').is(':checked')){      
      s_max=jQuery('#dt-max-price').val();
   }
   if(jQuery('#55').is(':checked')){     
      st_max=jQuery('#dt-max-price').val();
   }
```

});

3) When a radio option is selected, assign the minimum and maximum variable values as the dropdown value.

```
 jQuery('#36').on('click',function(){    
    jQuery('#dt-min-price').val(s_min);
    jQuery('#dt-max-price').val(s_max);
 });
 jQuery('#34').on('click',function(){    
    jQuery('#dt-min-price').val(r_min);
    jQuery('#dt-max-price').val(r_max);
 });
 jQuery('#55').on('click',function(){  
   jQuery('#dt-min-price').val(st_min);
   jQuery('#dt-max-price').val(st_max);
 });
```

Comment: To sum up: if you also want to change the content of the dropdowns, then first use `$('#dt-min-price').html(newContent);` in the click function and afterwards set the values. Everything as Jaithera explained.